# How to disable blur in Windows 10's Photo Viewer when zooming (or alternative programs)?

Tags: windows-10, photos, windows-photo-viewer

I work on pixel art stuff so this always bothers me. Windows 10's default imageviewer does this to the images:

[image]

and while it's great for some types of images it doesn't work with what I usually have to look at. Something that bothers me is that when I close the program it shows the image without blurriness for a split second, so I wonder if I there's a way to completely disable the feature. Good program alternatives are also appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The default Windows 10 app for viewing pictures is *Photos*. On the other hand *Windows Photo Viewer* is an older app, which I - and many others - preferred. You can still enable this program on Windows 10 to get the old behaviour back.
[Here's](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/14312-restore-windows-photo-viewer-windows-10-a.html) A tutorial on how to do it, although it requires some registry edits, which always seem a bit scary. It worked perfectly for me though. See comparison below:

[Blurry - Photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP03I.png)

[Not blurry - Windows Photo Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkKsv.png)

It also offeres greater maginification and seems more responsive / is quicker to open

Answer (score 1):

*Updated answer:*
Now I'd recommend **ImageGlass** instead.
A more fully featured and customizable image viewer that also do not apply any anti-aliasing:
https://imageglass.org/

*Original answer:*
You could give 'Emulsion' a try: https://arturkovacs.github.io/emulsion-website/
It's fast and minimalist with entirely optional anti-aliasing.

Comment: Emulsion is now unfortunately officially deprecated and unsupported by the author

Comment: Luckily it's not what I'm recommending anyway, I edited the answer to put more emphasis on my updated recommendation

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to download a new program, you could use Paint (Windows accessories>Paint). Open your image, select view, zoom in and there are the pixels. Check the grid lines box to make the pixel boundaries even clearer.